# Job Description on CV

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

I want to write a title (e.g. "Math Teacher") and one short sentence (e.g. "High School teacher at Kellog's school of Wizards") on my CV that describes the job I had during a summer.

The company I worked for had the following business idea:

1. Get people to signup with their names and addresses
2. Take these names to a public bid between companies that provides energy & electricity.
3. The companies fight on who gets the customers - the one with the lowest prize wins.

My job was to *call* the people who had signed up for the email newsletter, and convince them to *signup for an auction*. I thought my title should be "Telemarketer" or "Energy Telemarketer". The sentence: I don't know.

Comment: So you were not a teacher, right? *i.e* stands for *that is*, if you wanted to give an example, you should have said: *e.g.* which stands for *for example*. (: In other words, it's a good idea to edit your post and clarify it so that you get better help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about resume writing

Comment: @bib No, because it's also relevant in any social situations where I have to describe my previous job in english.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could find this by searching a bit on Linked-in, also it could be more on-topic in [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) S.E. site.

However these are my suggestions and you can pick among them depending on what suits your position the best:

> #### Jacob the King
>
> #### Energy Telemarketer at ABC Energy Co.
>
> - Identified new clients in the specific target market
> - Contacted clients to *bring business to the company* [or for whatever purpose it was]
> - Communicated directly with people in *English* [or another language]
> - Working to competitive targets with a high turnover

Comment: will definitely keep *the King*

Comment: Hahaha, just picked something matching your gravatar. (: